# Altering the value of query string in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a url that looks like this - `http://localhost:8000/houses/search?address=us&page=1&recent=false`.

On the view (blade) file, i am doing some check to determine the value of `recent`. Using the above url as an example, if the value of `recent` is true, i want to change the value else it should remain the same. 
Also, if the url does not have a query string with name - `recent`, it should be added with its value.

For example, if the url looks like this - `http://localhost:8000/houses/search?address=us&page=1`, after doing my checks and the value of `recent` is true, the url should now look like this  - `http://localhost:8000/houses/search?address=us&page=1&recent=true`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Based on your example http://localhost:8000/houses/search?address=us&page=1, where do you get your recent value from?

Comment: Have a look into what JLRDW said in this topic https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-can-i-get-id-from-url?page=1. Basically, pass the uri as requests through a route to a controller. At the controller.. You can deal with any logic there.